# Denying load of chrome-extension. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, json, web

I am learning JavaScript. I installed nodejs live server but when I run this, I am getting an error. I tried the given solutions but couldn't solve it. Can someone please explain in detail how to solve this problem? I didn't use any json files, only index.html and styles.css. I am new to programming, so please help me.

> Denying load of chrome-extension://iidnbdjijdkbmajdffnidomddglmieko/fonts/open-sans-v23-latin-regular.woff. Resources must be listed in the web_accessible_resources manifest key in order to be loaded by pages outside the extension.

I read the existing solutions but don't know how to use them. I am newbie, so couldn't understand it.

Answer (score 7):

Disabling "QuillBot for Chrome" extension worked for me too.

Comment: I checked a box in console settings called, "Selected Context Only", and it hides the error. But is there a way to solve the problem without disabling the extension? Also, will it be a problem if I keep this box checked? I don't have any idea about it.

Comment: Wow, it was a long shot, but it worked. Thanks 

Answer (score 4):

i tried by disabling one extension at a time and refreshed page to checck the error  and i found the culprit to be wordtune extension

Comment: Thank you for this. I disabled the extension, refreshed the page and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 2):

I'm also having this issue and I was able to find the culprit. Are you also using an extension "QuillBot for Chrome"? Disabling this extension worked for me.

Just open Google Chrome the go to extension and disable the extension. Refresh your browser and the error should be gone.

Comment: Yes, I am using this extension. But I can't disable it as it is necessary for me. Is there any other way to solve this problem? I searched this on ChatGPT and tried everything, but still couldn't solve the problem. So, please let me know if you find any other way. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the simple steps for getting rid of this kind of error.

1. Go to chrome://extensions/
2. Find an extension with ID : `iidnbdjijdkbmajdffnidomddglmieko` ( Check the url in the error message for extension ID. ID is given in the error.)
3. Disable this extension if it's not useful and refresh the page

OR

3. Click on details of that extension and enable `Allow access to file URLs` and then refresh the page

Answer (score 0):

you have to use google chrome without any accounts[image]